# Error function_clause?

Tags: erlang

Why is this not working? Can't figure this out. Seems to be something with the way strings are matched.
I keep getting an error `error:function_clause`.

```
-module(rna_transcription).
-export([to_rna/1, to_rna_nucleotide/1]).

to_rna(DNA) -> lists:map(fun to_rna_nucleotide/1, DNA).

to_rna_nucleotide("G") -> "C";
to_rna_nucleotide("C") -> "G";
to_rna_nucleotide("T") -> "A";
to_rna_nucleotide("A") -> "U".
```

Comment: The element of string is of type char, not string. Rewrite using to_rna_nucleotide($G) -> "C"; .

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Thanks that worked. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element of string is of type char, not string.

```
to_rna_nucleotide($G) -> $C;
to_rna_nucleotide($C) -> $G;
to_rna_nucleotide($T) -> $A;
to_rna_nucleotide($A) -> $U.
```

Comment: Can you change it to: `-> $C` etc... As the result should still be a string.